# Foreground Service for sensor data stops after a small period of time

Tags: android, service, sensors, foreground

I am developing an android application where sensor data are recorded from the sensors, displayed in graphs and also stored in an SQLite database. I want the sensor data process to run when the app is  not visible in the screen, so i designed a foreground service for that purpose. The service seems to be running ok for about 5 min and then the app stops recording sensor data.

I am trying to understand why this is occuring. The app in the emulator is not turned off, the screen is lit. I have declared my foreground service, (i call startForeground on onCreate() function of the service).

I am showcasing part of the code of the foreground service:

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        startMyOwnForeground()
    else
        startForeground(1, Notification())

    sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    initSensors()
    registerListeners()
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private fun startMyOwnForeground() {

val chan = NotificationChannel(
    "MyChannelId",
    "My Foreground Service",
    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
)

val manager = (getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager)!!
manager!!.createNotificationChannel(chan)


val notificationBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
    this, "MyChannelId"
)
val notification: Notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
    .setContentTitle("App is running on foreground")
    .setPriority(NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon)
    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
    .setChannelId("MyChannelId")
    .build()

startForeground(1, notification)
}
```

And small excerpt from the sensor recording process:

```
private fun initSensors()
{
    accelerometerSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
    accelometerSensorEventListener = object: SensorEventListener
    {
        override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?) {

            for (i in 0 until event!!.values.size)
            {
                accelerometerValues[i] = event.values[i]
            }

            //keep the time stamp for each event
            if (!acceleratorTimeStampSet)
            {
                acceleratorTimeStampSet = true
                initialAcceleratorTimeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
            }
            //set the timestamps
            val timestampX: Long = System.currentTimeMillis() - initialAcceleratorTimeStamp
            accelerometerValuesTimeStampCounter ++
            //store the timestamps
            accelerometerValuesTimeStamps.add(timestampX)



            val accelSensorTriplets = ArrayList<Float>(3)
            if (accelSensorTriplets.size == 0)
            {
                accelSensorTriplets.add(0, event.values[0])
                accelSensorTriplets.add(1, event.values[1])
                accelSensorTriplets.add(2, event.values[2])
            }
            else
            {
                accelSensorTriplets.set(0, event.values[0])
                accelSensorTriplets.set(1, event.values[1])
                accelSensorTriplets.set(2, event.values[2])
            }
            //add a dateTime Object value to the array
            val dateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
            if (!allTimeStampsAccel.contains(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-d hh:mm:ss")))) {
                allTimeStampsAccel.add(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-d hh:mm:ss")))
                if (!allTimeStamps.contains(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-d hh:mm:ss")))) {
                    allTimeStamps.add(dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-d hh:mm:ss")))
                }
                var pair1 = Pair<Float, String>(
                    accelSensorTriplets.get(0),
                    allTimeStampsAccel.get(allTimeStampsAccel.size - 1)
                )
                var pair2 = Pair<Float, String>(
                    accelSensorTriplets.get(1),
                    allTimeStampsAccel.get(allTimeStampsAccel.size - 1)
                )
                var pair3 = Pair<Float, String>(
                    accelSensorTriplets.get(2),
                    allTimeStampsAccel.get(allTimeStampsAccel.size - 1)
                )
           

 var pairArrayList = ArrayList<Pair<Float, String>>(3)
                pairArrayList.add(pair1)
                pairArrayList.add(pair2)
                pairArrayList.add(pair3)
                accelerometerAllValuesForStore.add(pairArrayList)
                Log.d(
                    "DATA",
                    "accel data with timestamp : ${allTimeStampsAccel.get(allTimeStampsAccel.size - 1)}"
                )
            }
            //add the data for the accelerometer chart
            Log.d("SQL" , "ACCEL ${allTimeStampsAccel.get(allTimeStampsAccel.size-1)}")

        }

        override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int) {

        }
    }
```

Any help on why this behaviour is occuring is appreciated.

Lampros

Answer (score 0):

On a additional note, the onDestroy method of the service is immediatelly called witin the service execution...here is the code from the onStartCommand of the service:

```
   override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
                startMyOwnForeground()
            else
                startForeground(1, Notification())        }

        //        //Power management
        //        //Power management
        val am = applicationContext.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE)
        val pm = getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "myapp:mywakelocktag")
        wl!!.acquire()
        SetAlarm(applicationContext)

        sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        initSensors()
        registerListeners()

        return START_STICKY

    }
```

Why does the onDestroy gets called instantly?